# How to start and stop redis server in a jenkins build?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi I am configuring jenkins build for my rails project.

My project uses redis for caching.

So, my build steps goes as

1. start redis server
2. run specs
3. stop redis server.

Problem:

If I have all these steps in as a single build step, though spec fails, jenkins returns 'success'(because of last command passes)

If I have the 'stop redis server' command in a seperate build step, since the rspec fails, this steps doesn't run at all.

So, how can I achieve, "Jenkins build should fail if spec fails and still it should run the next step(stop the redis server)" ?

Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (single) build step:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

# start Redis
service redis-server start

# run specs and save exit code
bundle exec rake --trace
STATUS=$?

# stop Redis
service redis-server stop

# return with saved exit code
exit $STATUS
```